# Visual Studio cannot open or save Python .py files

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013

so im working on a text game in python, and am working on this at both school and home.

I recently started using Visual studio and love the program, however i found that it cannot open or save properly as a .py file, which i need to do to be able to work on the file at school.

I have installed python tools for visual studio and it works great, but i can only work with files in a .pyroj format.

Does anyone with Visual Studio experience know any way to save and open .py's in Visual Studio?

Many thanks

Comment: Installing [Python Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ea113de-a009-46cd-99f5-65ef0595f937) from Microsoft might help.

Comment: Have done, works great, can edit, but only when theyre in .pyproj format. I shall update psot to make this clearer

Answer (score 0):

As for opening files, if you right click the .py file, open with, and then select visual studio.

I know it's not really a solution, but you may want to try PyCharm, I prefer it to IDLE, and it has several customisation options to make it look like visual studio.

Hope it helps.